# Vagrant vm + apache permission denied for mkdir()

Tags: php, shell, permissions, vagrant

I am using vagrant to run my vm using ubuntu, apache, etc.
This is running on my OSX host.

Everything works fine until my php application tries to create a folder, files within that folder, etc.
I get Permission denied.
What am I missing on the provision / configuration of the vagrant file?

Comment: Can you post your Vagrantfile for us to see.  I use Vagrant for PHP dev and might be able to help

Answer (score 25):

in this case, if you're using Vagrant + Apache2.

the solution is:

1. edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf;
2. Search for **User** and **Group** directives
3. Change these lines to:

   ```
   User vagrant
   Group vagrant
   ```
4. run `sudo service apache2 restart`

its not possible to change /vagrant directory owner to www-data (apache user);

Anyway, it works for me.

Comment: This is what I did. I also needed to change the group on the session data folder so PHP could properly read / write session data (on CentOS): `chown root:vagrant /var/lib/php/session`. I deleted existing session in that session folder, and everything worked fine after that.

Comment: Which apache? The one on the host machine or guest VM?

Comment: Guest Virtual Machine.

Comment: It's worth noting that on Ubuntu 16.10 (and possibly 16.04) Vagrant started using the 'ubuntu' user and group instead of 'vagrant'. The answer is still a valid solution to the problem, just change the user/group.

Answer (score 5):

Edit Vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the owner on the folder that php is trying to write to, to the apache user which is normally www-data... ssh into the vagrant box and try:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data <dirname>
```

That should work... if it does then just add that to what ever provisioner you are using.

Comment: Yep, and an alternative (but similar) approach is to run Apache as the vagrant user. I've done this successfully.

Comment: Jonathan it would be handy to have that as an answer